# How to correctly make API calls in chrome extension MV3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am mostly confused about the documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/to-service-workers/#replace-xmlhttprequest

I want to make a API POST request where I would pass user input as a parameter, and get a response from the remote server (that I will be hosting). The documentation instructs to use fetch(), which I will be doing.

But I am confused about the wording. Isn't backend code logic in the API considered "external javascript"? Of course, I won't be extracting the code to execute within the extension environment but it is still external logic that will be hidden.

In MV3, all logic must be contained within the extension package. From my understanding, this means that we can't call remotely hosted javascript, as well as API calls (I think) because the API endpoints themselves have a separate code on a remotely hosted server.

I am also concerned about passing user inputs to an external server for the review process.

Do we need to submit these code separately for the review process? Can I use fetch() to make API calls?

Also please let me know if there are better forums I can ask this to, I apologize that its not directly related to programming.

Thank you

I tested this using Youtube Data API on my service worker and I was able to pass user input parameters and get a json response back. There were no errors. But I am more worried about the review process on this.

Comment: "external javascript" means an externally hosted code executed locally by your extension via `<script>` tag or eval. It's not related to posting a network request. You can suggest them to clarify their documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm that clears a lot thank you. You did say "externally", but does this apply to injected scripts that were packaged in the extensions and are defined in "web_accessible_resources"? Just want to make sure. I do have injection scripts and they run fine without errors.

Comment: Externally hosted means code outside your extension i.e. JS script loaded from an external server.